# MySQL - Same SQL query fast ,but very slow in Stored Procedures?

Tags: mysql

I had been stucked in this problem for more than 10 hours!

I had tried to add or remove the '**@**' before variables or params but nothing happened.

I really dont know whats going wrong , help please !

**QUERY**

```
select ClientId into @v1 from by_test_db1.recordcd where SN = 'abc';
select ClientId into @v2 from by_test_db1.log      where SN = 'abc';
select concat(@v1,@v2);
```

**SP**

```
delimiter $$
create procedure TEST(newSN varchar(50))
begin 
    declare v1 varchar(50);
    declare v2 varchar(50);
     start transaction;
        select ClientId into v1 from by_test_db1.recordcd where SN = newSN;
        select ClientId into v2 from by_test_db1.log      where SN = newSN;
        select concat(v1,v2);
     commit;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

**MySQL** version 5.7

Through there are **100 million** rows in the **recordcd** table ,the **QUERY** just ran fast and well, but the **SP** was running so slowly that it timed out and reported an error

**Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query**

I tried many ways but none of them worked, I don't know why there is such a ridiculous situation , I dont even know how to search the answer to this situation, so hope you big guys can help me , thank u.

Comment: Please include everything in the question (no links) And why are you using transactions in the sp?

Comment: The select statements aren't the issue the transaction is..

Comment: Simpler:  `SELECT CONCAT( ( SELECT ... ), ( SELECT ... ) );`

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65947563/same-sql-runs-fast-in-query-but-very-slowly-in-sp ?