# Same SQL runs fast in QUERY but very slowly in SP?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions

I had tried to add or remove the '@' before variables or params but nothing happened.

**QUERY**

```
 start transaction;
   set @recordClient = (select ClientId  from by_test_db1.recordcd where SN = 'abc' );
   set @logClient    = (select ClientId  from by_test_db1.log      where SN = 'abc' );
   select concat(@recordClient,@logClient);
 commit;
```

**SP**

```
delimiter $$
create procedure TEST(newSN varchar(50))
begin 
     start transaction;
        set @recordClient = (select ClientId  from by_test_db1.recordcd where SN = newSN );
        set @logClient    = (select ClientId  from by_test_db1.log      where SN = newSN );
        select concat(@recordClient,@logClient);
     commit;
end $$
delimiter ;

call TEST('abc');
```

MySQL version   **5.7**

Through there are **100 million** rows in the **recordcd** table ,the **QUERY** just ran fast and well, but the **SP** was running so slowly that it timed out and reported an error

**Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query**

I tried many ways but none of them worked, I don't know why there is such a ridiculous situation, I don't even know how to search the answer to this situation.

Comment: I understand neither why you have a transaction nor why you have a sproc. What's wrong with a standard join query?

Comment: dup of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936707/mysql-same-sql-query-fast-but-very-slow-in-stored-procedures ?

Answer (score 0):

**Add indexes**

```
INDEX(SN)  -- on both tables
```

**Simplify query**

```
SELECT  CONCAT(
           ( select ClientId  from by_test_db1.recordcd where SN = 'abc' ),
           ( select ClientId  from by_test_db1.log      where SN = 'abc' ) );
```